# Progress spinner not showing during long-running operation

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I am writing a card-playing app for android. At times the computer player can take 1-3s to play, during which time I'd like to display the circular indeterminate spinner. The problem is that the spinner does not show during this "thinking" time, although it does show in testing.

Here's my spinner snippet:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressCircle"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/draw_and_discard_piles"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

and the corresponding code snippet for inflating it during OnCreate:

```
    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressCircle);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and for displaying it:

```
void showSpinner(final boolean show) {
    spinner.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    spinner.invalidate();
}
```

During the long-running play I do the following, where DiscardOrDrawThread is an inner class:

```
    //if Computer, we decide here whether to draw or discard
    final long playerStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    class DiscardOrDrawThread extends Thread {
        private Game.PileDecision pickFrom;
        DiscardOrDrawThread() {
            pickFrom = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pickFrom = tryDiscardOrDrawPile(isFinalTurn, deck.discardPile.peekNext(), deck.drawPile.peekNext());
        }
    }
    DiscardOrDrawThread discardOrDrawThread = new DiscardOrDrawThread();

    myActivity.showSpinner(true);
    try {
        discardOrDrawThread.start();
        discardOrDrawThread.join();
    }catch(RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("takeTurn: thread join RuntimeException");
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted in takeTurn");
    }
    myActivity.showSpinner(false);
```

The actual playing code is working fine, and if I comment out the myActivity.showSpinner(false), then the spinner will show up correctly, starting at the beginning of the long-running section (tryDiscardOrDrawPile). But if it's not commented out, the spinner never shows.

Can anybody point me to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reimplemented my code using an AsyncTask (as many posts suggest for ProgressBars), as shown below, and everything now works properly.

```
       class DiscardOrDrawTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Game.PileDecision> {

        @Override
        protected Game.PileDecision doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final Game.PileDecision pickFrom = tryDiscardOrDrawPile(isFinalTurn, deck.discardPile.peekNext(), deck.drawPile.peekNext());
            return pickFrom;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            myActivity.showSpinner(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Game.PileDecision pickFrom) {
            myActivity.showSpinner(false);
            myActivity.animateComputerPickUpAndDiscard(playerMiniHandLayout, pickFrom);
        }
    }
    DiscardOrDrawTask discardOrDrawTask= new DiscardOrDrawTask();
    discardOrDrawTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Progress spinner not showing during long-running operation

Due to `discardOrDrawThread.join();`

> Why?

*`discardOrDrawThread.join();` causes the current thread(main UI-Thread) to pause execution until discardOrDrawThread's thread terminate*

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to do long-running operations in background

Comment: Ok, I previously moved the long-running operation onto a separate thread so that it wouldn't block the UI thread. Won't changing it to an AsyncTask give me the same problem where I need to wait for completion?

Comment: @Opus1217: remove `discardOrDrawThread.join();`  and do it as :` @Override
        public void run() {
            pickFrom = tryDiscardOrDrawPile(isFinalTurn, deck.discardPile.peekNext(), deck.drawPile.peekNext());
            myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             myActivity.showSpinner(false);
                        }
                    });
        }`

Comment: I tried several variations of what you suggested, but none of them worked. However, I have now re-implemented as an AsyncTask, and get the desired behavior by pushing all my post-task UI work into the onPostExecute method. See my answer.